# Overlay balance to credit and debit Line graph in PowerBI

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am creating a dashboard from a direct query. Using the line graph visulations I am plotting the transaction volumes and splitting them: Credit or Debit.
On the same graph I would like to overlay the current balance. Please see attached image. I would like to combine these two graphs but dont know how to. 
Any advice greatly welcomed!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Xds.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the visualization to a **Line and stacked column chart**. You can use **Account Balance** for the **Column series**.

The **Line values** is a little trickier.  You will need 2 new calculated measures, something like:

```
Credit = CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'My Table'[Volume] ) , 'My Table'[TxnMethod] = "Credit" )
```

Ditto for Debit.  Note I am guessing your aggregation for [Volume]. Then add those 2 new measures to the **Line values**.

Buried in the **Format** section under **Y-Axis** is the **Show secondary** switch, which I would turn on to get a separate Y-Axis for the Lines.